# Freeform Pro auto populated order form

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms

I've got a channel with CD's. So there are let say 10 entries.
Members can order these CD's. There is only one form to order the CD's.
It will look something like this:

```
<label>CD title 1:</label><select name="cd_title_one" id="freeform_quantity">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Quantity</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 etc...
</select>

<label>CD title 2:</label><select name="cd_title_two" id="freeform_quantity">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Quantity</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     etc...
    </select>
```

Is there a way to auto pupulate this with Freeform Pro? If not are there other solutions?

Tnx